# Git: save value of HEAD, whether it’s symbolic or detached

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to write a script which checks out some specified commit, does some things there (specifically: writes build timings to a file), then restores HEAD to the state it was when the script was invoked, modulo ignored files.

I’m happy to assume if necessary that there are no unstaged/uncommitted changes when it’s invoked — though I’d love to cover that case too, if it’s possible without too much hassle.

My best attempt looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CURREV=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`

git checkout $TARGETREV

[… test the build, and save timings in "timings-$TARGETREV.txt" …]

git checkout $CURREV
```

With this, HEAD ends up at the correct commit, but always in “detached HEAD” state, not at a branch that it may have been tracking previously.

If on the other hand I begin with `git symbolic-ref HEAD` instead of `git ref-parse HEAD`, then that works starting from a branch, but fails if `HEAD` is detached, with error `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref`.

**How can I save the current value of HEAD — whether it points to a branch, or is detached at a commit — and restore it later?**

Comment: What about something like this? `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git rev-parse HEAD`

Comment: You can probably just use the reflog. `git checkout whatever; do-stuff;  git checkout @{-1}`

Comment: @nj_ why not make that an answer?  It's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check for and handle the two cases.  Here's the slightly clumsy version making everything explicit:

```
if symbol=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD); then
    is_symbolic=true
else
    is_symbolic=false
    rev=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit 1 # rev-parse already gave err msg
fi
... code ...
if $is_symbolic; then
    git checkout -q $symbol
else
    git checkout -q $rev
fi
```

We then note that the two checkout cases can be collapsed into one, so we don't need to retain the `is_symbolic` state, just the appropriate string to pass to `git checkout`:

```
restore=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD) ||
    restore=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit 1
... code ...
git checkout -q $restore
```

---

Regarding this bit:

> I’m happy to assume if necessary that there are no unstaged/uncommitted changes when it’s invoked — though I’d love to cover that case too, if it’s possible without too much hassle.

If you look in git's `--exec-path`:

```
$ ls $(git --exec-path)
```

you will find a script named `git-sh-setup`.  In it, there are various `require` functions.  The one you want here is `require_clean_work_tree`.

Answer (score 1):

The reflog already keeps extensive track of the changes to various references.

```
#!/bin/bash

git checkout "$TARGETREV"

[… test the build, and save timings in "timings-$TARGETREV.txt" …]

git checkout @{-1}
```

As long as the intermediate steps don't checkout another commit or branch, `@{-1}` refers to what was checkout out before `git checkout "$TARGETREV"`.

Comment: I’ve accepted the other answer, but would accept both if I could — this is also very helpful, and may be what I end up using in my script.